# Add a bookmark in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'd like to know how I add a bookmark in Google Earth Engine. I need to add a marker to mark a certain area.

Answer (score 1):

1. Place a marker with the marker symbol in the map window:

[image]

2. Click "Get link" to get a link to the script with all the markers and geometries you created.

[image]

Example for the link to a script with the marker placed in Madrid: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7f2846bbfc13aeb2af4650aacfbc456b

Comment: can I add marker by command line?

Comment: Can you? Very likely with the Python API. Does it make sense? I don't think so.